# How to pass user input from one script to another in Python?

Tags: python

I'm creating a GUI application using PyQt5 and am struggling with passing a user input retrieved from a QLineEdit in the first script into the second script. 
The first script is a log-in page and I am trying to pass the username entered in the line edit box into the main application (which is a separate file) as it needs to be displayed in that interface.

I have researched this and have only come across methods which pass fixed variables such as 'x = 5' (constants) rather than a user input. How would I go about using a variable that could change at runtime? I have tried the

```
from __main__ import *
```

method in the called file and I've tried to convert the username variable into a string using 'str(username)' and setting the variable as global but it seems I still get the same error and when the second file is called and it crashes with no error being displayed. 
Here is the relevant code taken from different areas of the script:

file1.py

```
import os

global username
username = self.lineEdit_username.text()
username = str(username)
import file2
MainWindow.close() 
os.system('file2.py')
```

file2.py

```
from __main__ import *
print(username)  # just to check if the variable has been imported
```

I've tried researching this as much as I can before posting this but if I have missed a solution somwhere else please point me in the right direction.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Pass it as a [command line](docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html) argument?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I have done this, especially with PyQt, is utilizing classes and importing the file as a module. See the example below.

Pass_variable.py:

```
import tkinter as tk
class user_input(object):
    def get_input(self):
        def get_text():
            self.entry = user_entry.get()
            print(self.entry)
            root.destroy()

        root = tk.Tk()

        root.title('Name')

        user_entry = tk.Entry(root)
        user_entry.pack()
        user_entry.focus_set()

        okay_button = tk.Button(root,text='okay',command=get_text)
        okay_button.pack(side='bottom')
        root.mainloop()
```

retrieve_variable.py:

```
from Pass_variable import user_input

x = user_input()
x.get_input()
print(x.entry)
```

so you are basically importing the class `user_input` from the file `Pass_variable`, assigning `x` to the class and then anything that is under `self` is now stored in the `x` variable. So `x.entry` is the same thing as calling `self.entry` inside the pass_variable.py file.

Does this make sense?

Comment: This makes sense now that I have had a proper look - thanks! I'll give it a go and let you know how it goes. I have one question - will this still work if the pass_variable.py file is closed before the retrieve_variable.py is ran?

Comment: what do you mean 'closed'? As long as the .py files are in the same folder you can import it. It does not matter if the file is open in your IDE or not.